# UserRoles Table has additional UserId1 field after upgrade to .net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

I had a .net core 1.0 project works well. In the project I use Asp.net Identity library together with EF core and code first method, and extends the User and Role entity to my own, with an int primary key.

Recently I upgraded to .Net Core 2.0. However, when applying the database change, I noticed the UserRole table is updated as following

```
 [UserId1]
,[UserId]
,[RoleId]
,[Discriminator]
```

I tried to create a new database and this still happens, really don't know how to fix this issue. My classes are as following

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public enum UserCategory
    {
        Agent = 1,
        Inspector,
        ReInspector,
        Leader,
        Trainer,
        QaSupervisor,
        Manager,
        Admin
    }

    [Required]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ExtensionNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UserCategory Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; } = new List<UserRole>();
    public virtual ICollection<UserClaim> Claims { get; } = new List<UserClaim>();
    public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> Logins { get; } = new List<UserLogin>();

    public ICollection<CallRecord> CallRecords { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InspectionTaskDetail> InspectionTasks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InspectionTask> TaskCreated { get; set; }
}

 [Table("Roles")]
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{

}
```

In the Startup.cs, I add the Identity as following

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<CoreDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I seperate the repository into another library, and following the repository's project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>  
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="2.0.0-preview1-0643" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Core" Version="2.0.0-preview1-0643" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="2.0.0-preview1-0643" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.2" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Anyone has experienced similar issue before? Please ignore the MySql related code as my code supports multiple databases. This issue happens to the SQL server

Comment: Did you find a fix?